# Постинкремент при возвращении значения функции

Tags: c++, инкремент

Почему функция

```
int f(int k) { return k++; }
```

возвращает значение `k` вместо `k+1`, даже если записать ее в виде:

```
int f(int k) { return (k++); }
```

?

Comment: Задавая такие вопросы, вам не мешало бы сначала объяснить, почему вы ожидали возвращения значения `k+1`. Без этого вопрос звучит как "Почему 2+2 равно 4, а не 5". Не ясно, откуда даже мог возникнуть такой вопрос.

Comment: Но, если записать вот так -- `int f (int k) { return k++, k; }`, то вернет уже увеличенное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Именно потому что это постинкремент. Результат постинкремента - это значение **до** изменения. Наличие дополнительных скобок не меняет значения выражения. Если бы Вы записали:

```
k++;
return k;
```

то вернулось бы уже инкрементированное значение, т.к. после `;` переменная уже изменится.

Понимание эффекта возможно упростит использование функции вместо постинкремента вида:

```
int inc(int i) {
   int t = i;
   i = i + 1;
   return t;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что **постфиксный** инкремент дает в качестве значения выражения значение переменной *до* инкремента.

Вот и все. Хотите возвращать `k+1` - пишите `return ++k;`...

Answer (score 3):

В этом заключается смысл различия между пре-инкрементным оператором и пост-инкрементным оператором. Пост-инкрементный оператор возвращает значение переменной до ее инкремента.

Из стандарта c++ (5.2.6 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The value of a postﬁx ++ expression is **the value of its operand**.
>   [Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value —end note]

Если бы переменная `k` была бы объявлена как глобальная переменная

```
int k;

int f(){ return k++; }
```

то, действительно, после выхода из функции ее значение увеличилось бы на 1. Хотя тем не менее сама функция вернула бы исходное значение переменной.

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную программу

```
#include <iostream>

int k = 0;

int f(){ return k++; } 
int g( int k ){ return k++; } 

int main() 
{
    std ::cout << "f() = " << f() << std::endl;
    std ::cout << "k = " << k << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    k = 0;

    std ::cout << "g( k ) = " << g( k ) << std::endl;
    std ::cout << "k = " << k << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
f() = 0
k = 1

g( k ) = 0
k = 0
```

Обе функции вернули одно и то же значение `0`.
После вызова первой функции `k` увеличилась на `1`, так как функция имеет дело непосредственно с глобальной переменной. Во втором случае переменная `k` не изменилась, так как вторая функция имеет дело с копией значения переменной. Ее параметр - это локальная переменная функции.